# How to add external js file into vue cli app?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, menu, vue-cli

I am new to Vue and I am trying to convert html files which I have created in bootstrap into vue using vue cli. My bootstrap and style.css code is working perfectly but I am having issue in working my jquery code.when I am trying to run jquery code to open and close menu then its not working and I am not getting any errors as well..But my menu and jquery code is working fine without vue cli application. Can anyone help me please? Thanks

```
<script>
import $ from "jquery";
export default {
    name:'HomeComponent',
    
}

$(".menu-btn a").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".header").next().next(".nav-menu").addClass("active")
        //    $(".nav-menu").addClass("active");
});

$(".crose-icon a").click(function() {
    $(".nav-menu").removeClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You must not use Vue and JQuery together.

Comment: @GabrielWillemann Thanks for your reply. I am using on jquery for menu..

Comment: @GabrielWillemann because I am convert html pages to vue and those pages are designed using bootstrap.

Comment: I use bootstrap without JQuery (only CSS) and the events I do manually. But you can use https://bootstrap-vue.org if you want.